# USB-C dock or adapter to 2x or 3x HDMI for Dell XPS 13 9300

Tags: 20.04, dock, adapter, usb-c

Is anybody aware of a working USB-C to 2x or 3x HDMI adapter or dock for the Dell XPS 13 9300 and would be able to recommend any option to buy?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help or suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: I have two HDMI external monitors, but I used a mini-Display Port to HDMI cable for one of them. Beware of the cheaper Dell portable docks - they appear to have multiple monitor connectors (HDMI, mini-DP and/or DP) but only one can be used at a time.

Comment: But the XPS has only 2 USB-C ports?

Comment: @B.Tanner so your mini-Display port to HDMI cable is a 1 : 1? I need 1 : 2 or better 1 : 3. RIght now I have a USB-C to HDMI adapter.

Comment: Have a look at the Dell WD19 series of docks. There is only one USB-C connection but the dock can drive at least two monitors over HDMI/DP/mini-DP using that one USB-C connection (possibly three monitors I'm not sure), also powers the XPS, and has USB-A sockets for external keyboards, mice etc. Basically plug one USB-C cable in and your little laptop becomes a full multi-monitor desktop computer.

Comment: Cool, will give it a shot. @B.Tanner: I have another Dell computer (Tower XPS 8940) do you know by any chance how I could split the NVIDIA VGA HDMI output? USB-C connector seems not to work with `nouveau` and thus I'm stuck with single monitor setup.

Comment: I am not familiar with it but from the picture of the back on the Dell web site I would think you just need a DP to HDMI cable for your second monitor (and another for a third monitor...)

Comment: @B.Tanner well yeah, I have 1x HDMI / 1x DVI for the NVIDIA GTX card, but the USB-C video connector seems not to work becuase of some Nvidia drivers quirks I guess. I will have to see. Thanks.